# JavaFX Table isn't displaying data

Tags: java, javafx

I've taken this code directly from another source with proof it was working initially, however upon putting it in my own Eclipse IDE the table headers are displaying but the data in the table is not. I've been having this problem with other examples of tables where either the table data is missing. I'm pretty sure the individual objects added to the table are generated and added correctly so I'm not sure what's wrong. Here is the code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSampleMain extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {

      TableView<UserAccount> table = new TableView<UserAccount>();

      // Create column UserName (Data type of String).
      TableColumn<UserAccount, String> userNameCol //
              = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("User Name");



    // Create column Email (Data type of String).
      TableColumn<UserAccount, String> emailCol//
              = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("Email");

      // Create column FullName (Data type of String).
      TableColumn<UserAccount, String> fullNameCol//
              = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("Full Name");

      // Create 2 sub column for FullName.
      TableColumn<UserAccount, String> firstNameCol//
              = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("First Name");

      TableColumn<UserAccount, String> lastNameCol //
              = new TableColumn<UserAccount, String>("Last Name");

      // Add sub columns to the FullName
      fullNameCol.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

      // Active Column
      TableColumn<UserAccount, Boolean> activeCol//
              = new TableColumn<UserAccount, Boolean>("Active");

      // Defines how to fill data for each cell.
      // Get value from property of UserAccount. .
      userNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("userName"));
      emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("email"));
      firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
      lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
      activeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));

      // Set Sort type for userName column
      userNameCol.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
      lastNameCol.setSortable(false);

      // Display row data
      ObservableList<UserAccount> list = getUserList();
      table.setItems(list);

      table.getColumns().addAll(userNameCol, emailCol, fullNameCol, activeCol);

      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
      root.getChildren().add(table);

      stage.setTitle("TableView (o7planning.org)");

      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
  }

  private ObservableList<UserAccount> getUserList() {

      UserAccount user1 = new UserAccount(1L, "smith", "smith@gmail.com", //
              "Susan", "Smith", true);
      UserAccount user2 = new UserAccount(2L, "mcneil", "mcneil@gmail.com", //
              "Anne", "McNeil", true);
      UserAccount user3 = new UserAccount(3L, "white", "white@gmail.com", //
              "Kenvin", "White", false);

      ObservableList<UserAccount> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(user1, user2, user3);
      return list;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }
}
```

With the UserAccount class:

```
package application;

public class UserAccount {

   private Long id;
   private String userName;
   private String email;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private boolean active;

   public UserAccount(Long id, String userName, String email, //
           String firstName, String lastName, boolean active) {
       this.id = id;
       this.userName = userName;
       this.email = email;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.active = active;
   }

   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getUserName() {
       return userName;
   }

   public void setUserName(String userName) {
       this.userName = userName;
   }

   public String getEmail() {
       return email;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
       this.email = email;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public boolean isActive() {
       return active;
   }

   public void setActive(boolean active) {
       this.active = active;
   }

}
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and the table is filled for me. Your issue lies elsewhere it seems.

Comment: Well that's confusing, maybe I have a buggy version of JavaFX if that's even possible.

Comment: If you are having the same issue with other examples, it may be your Java version is not up to date. Be sure you are running the latest jdk.

Comment: Highly unlikely it is your Java version. This is pretty basic functionality that has been stable for a long time. Much more likely that you haven't saved or compiled or deployed something. Try cleaning and rebuilding the project and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I think you should be using simplestringproperty in your Useraccount class

Comment: Just verified (now I am back at my computer) that this works for me too, with the code exactly as posted.